# Laravel Passport API with Javascript

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Till now I was storing access token in local storage. Now I want to move it into cookies.

So I added \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class, into Kernel.php. I also changed my axios call:

```
axios.get('/forum', {
    params: {
      filterBy: vm.filterBy,
      filterDirection: vm.filterDirection,
      theme: vm.theme
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      //'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken,
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN':window.Laravel.csrfToken
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    vm.posts=response.data
  }).catch(function (error) {});
```

You can see that I commented Authorization header where I was sending access token from local storage. I see that CSRF token is added in request header and that access token is saved in X-XSRF-TOKEN. There is also a Cookie with value: XSRF-TOKEN: (token value).

Now I am getting error with: Route[login] not defined.

Perhaps problem is that in Cookie value there is XSRF-TOKEN instead of laravel_token ?

Login api call

```
axios.post('/login', {
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
}).then(response => {
   const token = response.data.access_token

   localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
   localStorage.setItem('username', credentials.username)
   resolve(response)
}).catch(error => {
   reject(error)
})
```

And on back-end I then create token with:

```
$response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                        'grant_type' => 'password',
                        'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                        'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                        'username' => $request->username,
                        'password' => $request->password,
                    ]
            ]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Comment: I don't see any change in this code that would trigger that specific error. Did you add a call somewhere to `route('login')`?

Comment: @TravisBritz What you mean by route('login)?

Comment: I mean do you have a view or code anywhere that tries to create a link to the named route `'login'`?

Comment: @TravisBritz I have updated post

Comment: Where is your login route defined?

Comment: In api.php like that: Route::post('/login','AuthController@login');

Comment: Remember that anything defined in `api.php` will be prefiex with `/api`, e.g. `/api/login` (your axios code is posting to `/login`?)

Comment: I have baseURL set in settings and api call goes through

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of chrome to make sure the baseURL is actually being applied?

Comment: Yes, as I sad api call goes through I also get a response, but there is not laravel_token

Comment: I'm guessing that's because the `CreateFreshApiToken` is in the `web` middleware group, which is not applied to routes defined in `api.php` - so no auth cookie sent back by `/api/login`. I don't know why that would cause `Route[login] not defined` though - that indicates server-side code is trying to generate a url from a missing named route `login`.

Comment: It's creating that error because no access token is sent. If I send it with Authorization header it works fine, but then I need to use local storage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188240/discussion-between-travis-britz-and-miko).